# How to access the content created date rather than the date created of a file in Python?

Tags: python, windows, date

I am writing a program that moves files based on their creation date however the creation date retrieved from ctime() can sometimes change on windows when files are copied but the content created date seems to stay consistent.Is the a way to retrieve this date in Python as it doesn't change when the file is copied or modified?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

Comment: I'm no looking for modification date but rather the specific contents created date in the details pane of the properties section of a file in windows

Comment: That's not file-system metadata. It depends on metadata in a particular file type's header, which is made available by shell interfaces. That shifts the problem into COM programming and requiring PyWin32 or comtypes.